# jquery attr stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very much sure it was working previously but don't know why it stop working

My script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var Position = $("#test .active_r").attr('value');
        });
```

My HTML

```
<div id="test">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    A Shift</label><div class="color10">
                        <div class="color12">
                            <div class="color11">
                                <span class="radio_span" id="spanOndutyPosition0" onclick="ActiveRadioOndutyPosition(0)">
                                    <input type="radio" class="hidden_class" name="groupsettingOnDutyPosition" id="radiosettingOnDutyPosition0"
                                        value="A Shift"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    B Shift</label><div class="color10">
                        <div class="color12">
                            <div class="color11">
                                <span class="radio_span active_r" id="spanOndutyPosition1" onclick="ActiveRadioOndutyPosition(1)">
                                    <input type="radio" class="hidden_class" name="groupsettingOnDutyPosition" id="radiosettingOnDutyPosition1"
                                        value="B Shift"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    C Shift</label><div class="color10">
                        <div class="color12">
                            <div class="color11">
                                <span class="radio_span" id="spanOndutyPosition2" onclick="ActiveRadioOndutyPosition(2)">
                                    <input type="radio" class="hidden_class" name="groupsettingOnDutyPosition" id="radiosettingOnDutyPosition2"
                                        value="C Shift"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    D Shift</label><div class="color10">
                        <div class="color12">
                            <div class="color11">
                                <span class="radio_span" id="spanOndutyPosition3" onclick="ActiveRadioOndutyPosition(3)">
                                    <input type="radio" class="hidden_class" name="groupsettingOnDutyPosition" id="radiosettingOnDutyPosition3"
                                        value="D Shift"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    Standby</label><div class="color10">
                        <div class="color12">
                            <div class="color11">
                                <span class="radio_span" id="spanOndutyPosition10" onclick="ActiveRadioOndutyPosition(10)">
                                    <input type="radio" class="hidden_class" name="groupsettingOnDutyPosition" id="radiosettingOnDutyPosition10"
                                        value="Standby"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

It should give me value of Position variable but its undefined, any body know why attr is not working, don't kill me if its too simple. i worked a lot on it

Comment: you're getting any error message in the console?

Comment: @webeno no just getting undefined

Comment: @RUJordan: I can get it by manny methods but i want to get it by attr, why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `.active_r` class is on a `<span>`, which doesn't have `value` attribute.

So, just target the correct element and use `.val()`, like:

```
$("#test .active_r :checked").val();
```

Answer (score 4):

Element with `active_r` is a span... Try...

```
var Position = $("#test .active_r input[type=radio]").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector in not targetting inner input(type radio) element. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var Position = $("#test .active_r input").attr('value');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var Position = $("#test .active_r").find('input').val();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var Position = $("#test .active_r").find('input').attr('value');
     alert(Position)
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h82vE/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get value of radio button inside span having class **active_r** .
Because there is no value attribute on span having class **active_r**

if i am right then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var Position = $("#test .active_r input[type=radio]").attr('value');
             // OR
            var Position = $("#test .active_r input[type=radio]").val();
});
```

This might help you.